# Не отображается спиннер в ProgressDialog

Tags: android

Имеется  ProgressDialog

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.setMessage("Идет получение данных ...");
pDialog.show();
```

Отображение происходит, однако слева нет крутящегося спиннера. Не понимаю в чем может быть проблема

Comment: попробуйте добавить `dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);`

Comment: Поставил, всё по-прежнему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось все предельно просто: цвет спиннера был белый и на белом фоне его конечно же было не видно.

Добавил следующий код в values/style.xml

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Крутящийся спиннер появляется если указать:

```
pDialog.setIndeterminate(true); //а не false как у вас
```

P.S. С недавних пор `ProgressDialog` объявлен врагом народа - тьфу, `deprecated` :)

Comment: Поставил true, все равно не работает. Не понимаю, в чем может быть причина